# Pass data to controller in container view

Tags: ios, swift3, uicontainerview

I've got the following setup: a collection view with menu headers and menu items, when I select a menu item it should update the content on the right side of the view. In the right side of the view, I have a label and a segmented control.

When I select an item, it should update the container views both (they have a controller with embed segue). When I select the segmented control, the different view controller will be loaded.

Now I tried this:

`var selectedItem: String!
 var services: [String]!`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Loaded collectionView and reloaded
    selectedItem = services[section].items[row]
}
```

Then, I use `prepare(for:sender:)` to pass `selectedItem` to the controller that is being shown on the screen. However, this doesn't work, I think because the controller is already loaded.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "overviewSegue" {
            let controller = segue.destination as! ServiceOverViewController
            if let item = selectedItem {
                controller.setupViewWithService(service: item)
            }
        }
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.titleLabel.text = services[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row].name
        let overview = services[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]
        selectedItem = overview
    }
```

How can I select an item in the collectionView, set the data in both of the controllers in the containerView?

Comment: Have you created segue from collectionViewCell to ContainerView?

Comment: No, I have a container view in the layout which has an embed segue to the controller for that container view. I'm not quite sure how a segue from collectionViewCell to containerView should fix it?

Comment: I'm asking this because there is no call for `perfromSegue`?

Comment: I can't call performSegue, because the embed segue only happens once, I believe. So it only executes once, so it doesn't get updated when I tap a cell.

Comment: Yes you can declare one method in your base class pass those parameters you want in that method now, come to your home class which is also inherited from base class define that method here and handle coditation in switch case _yourContainer `show/hide` logic & don't forget to call  ` [_segmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];'

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the problem correctly, but you could use a custom delegate which you could set when the embed segue happens

Answer (score 0):

You can remove segue to `ServiceOverViewController` and then in `_, didSelectItemAt:` method:

1. Instantiate `ServiceOverViewController` from current storyboard
2. Assign item to this controller: `controller.setupViewWithService(service: item)`
3. Present controller.

Code will look something like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.titleLabel.text = services[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row].name
        if let overview = services[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]{

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier :"ServiceOverViewController") as! ServiceOverViewController
        viewController.setupViewWithService(service: item)
        self.present(viewController, animated: true)
    }

}
```